# Counting node attributes using succesors on a directed graph

Tags: python, networkx

I am currently working on a power distribution reliability index tool for radial networks for my engineering dissertation using `NewtworkX` and `Python`. I am struggling to write a command which will add to my accumulator all node attributes downstream of a particular edge which meets a certain condition. I've tried using the successors feature `NetworkX` offers however it will only count first successor that meets the edge condition instead of all downstream the directed path. I'm seeking guidance as this is confusing me and I can't seem to work my around this simple task.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H=nx.DiGraph()

H.add_node(1, loads=2)
H.add_node(2, loads=2)
H.add_node(3, loads=5)
H.add_node(4, loads=5)

H.add_edge(1,2,fault=True, switch=True)
H.add_edge(2,3,fault=False, switch=True)
H.add_edge(3,4,fault=False, switch=True)

nx.draw(H)
plt.show()

a=0
for n1,n2 in H.edges():
    if H[n1][n2]['fault']==True:
        a=a+H.node[n2]['loads']
            for n in H.successors(n2):
                a=a+H.node[n]['loads']
```

My algorithm returns `a=7` and the correct answer would be `a=12` and so on for all edges that meet the criteria. Obviously is me that is writing the wrong instruction.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Could you explain why you expect 12?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you want to get all of the successors so you can use a breadth first search like this

```
import networkx as nx

H=nx.DiGraph()

H.add_node(1, loads=2)
H.add_node(2, loads=2)
H.add_node(3, loads=5)
H.add_node(4, loads=5)

H.add_edge(1,2,fault=True, switch=True)
H.add_edge(2,3,fault=False, switch=True)
H.add_edge(3,4,fault=False, switch=True)


source = 1
a = H.node[source]['loads']
nofault = [t for s,t in nx.bfs_edges(H,source=source) if not H.edge[s][t]['fault']]
a += sum(H.node[t]['loads'] for t in nofault)
print(a) #12
```

Comment: Aric thank you so much for your advice, the algorithm is working properly now and I only had to create an accumulator so I can "automate" the source assignation which can be any particular node at a time. Again, thank so much!